# Troubling Operation not supported ...WCF Test Client ...{Receive OperationName}Response

Tags: workflow-services

Good Morning,

I'm trying to beat an end of year deadline and running into the error in the screenshot. I've been through my WF service several times to no avail. One thing that I think has meaning but I 'm not able to make the connection is how Response is added to the end of the Receive OperationName.

[image]

As mentioned above note how the error has Response added right to the end of the OperationName. It seems significant but I can't figure out why.

[image]

Also note the Content message of the Receive and SendReplyToReceive has a message type of null. (I'm going with the fact that it is inferred).

Code for the RequestDataContract

```
[DataContract]
public class LiftDataExchangeRequest
{


    //pretty simple we only have one thing we want from the client in request
    [DataMember]
    public String UserName{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Password{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ExchangeEnumerations Action { get; set; }

}
```

Code for the Response:

```
public class LiftDataExchangeResponse
{
    public XmlDocument WorkoutData { get; set; }
}
```

I'll gladly post anything else needed to help track this down and I would be very grateful to any additional information or reading.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is a limitation of the visual tool you're using (WCF Test Client), it is not designed to handle all possible services - there are some types that will prevent it from working. However, there's nothing wrong with your actual service.

Comment: What do you know? Usually I am doing something wrong. Thanks for checking and how do I test then. Write a test client / harness?